# Combining two SVG elements into one for continuous gradient

Tags: svg

I'm trying to add animation into an SVG which has a path with a semi transparent gradient. The end effect is to have something like a lift (elevator) moving up and down inside the tower in the middle. I'm doing this by moving a rectangle up and down under a path that has hole for windows, blocking each one in turn. I have the movement sorted but it's the transparency that is breaking things up.

[image]

The main `path` has a linear gradient with semi transparent stops on it and if I apply the gradient to a group containing the lift and the skyline I can see the lift through the skyline. If both items were 100% solid then the effect works as intended.

I'm tacking this on to an existing project as a proof of concept so I don't get to massively restructure the SVG. And I'm building it using D3

Here's a simple version doing the same thing

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 200 300">
 <defs>
   <linearGradient id="lingrad_5" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="600.0027" y1="539.9998" x2="600.0027" y2="361.8376"><stop offset="0" style="stop-color:#2D4B69;stop-opacity:0.6"></stop><stop offset="0.9949" style="stop-color:#004868;stop-opacity:0.85"></stop></linearGradient>
 </defs>
 <g fill="url(#lingrad_5)">
  <rect width="100" height="50" x="30" y="10" />
  <rect width="40" height="40" x="10" y="30" />
 </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: do you need the transparency to change in the gradient? i.e would a fixed transparency be OK?

Comment: You can force a constant opacity using a filter, but since you have a gradient in your opacity that makes things quite difficult. I would take a different tack - draw unfilled boxes over your windows and animate a gradient fill in each of them with offset timing to make it look like a lift is passing behind.

Comment: @RobertLongson The current design has a transparency with gradient, but it's actually not working on the production. I was planning to fix it in this same step but I'd rather add this animation if it's one or the other. What's your solution?

Comment: apply the opacity to the g, but then you can only have a single opacity for the whole thing.